# How to replace comma with space in python list

Tags: python, list

I want to replace comma to space in the list. How can i do that? Thanks

**input:**

```
host_dict['actives'] = list(get_po_bound_ints['result'][1]['portChannels'][mac_to_eth2]['activePorts'].keys())
```

**output:**

```
[{'actives': ['PeerEthernet23',
                             'PeerEthernet24',
                             'Ethernet23',
                             'Ethernet22'],
```

Comment: you want to make `[{'actives': ['PeerEthernet23'  'PeerEthernet24'  'Ethernet23' 'Ethernet22']` ??

Comment: When a list is displayed, the items are separated by commas.  But the commas are not actually part of the value.

Comment: Yes, I want  [{'actives': ['PeerEthernet23'  'PeerEthernet24'  'Ethernet23' 'Ethernet22']

Comment: It would make more sense to join the list as a string: [{'actives': 'PeerEthernet23 PeerEthernet24 Ethernet23 Ethernet22'}

Comment: `["A" "B" "C"]` = `["ABC"]`  , may I ask why would you want to do that?

Comment: I solved with this 
active_bounds = ''.join(i for i in str(host_dict['actives']).split(','))

Comment: Please include the input data so we can see what is being converted. All we need is whatever `host_dict['actives'] = list(get_po_bound_ints['result'][1]['portChannels'][mac_to_eth2]['activePorts'].keys())` is. Your desired strings don't have spaces in them. You are seeing the string representation of a list of strings. Do you want `activities: "PeerEthernet23 PeerEthernet24 ..."` - that is, a single string with list's values separated by spaces?

Comment: @ONURMODACI It does exactly what my solution does, doesn't it?

Comment: @ombk - I'm confused about your example. `[{'actives': ['PeerEthernet23'  'PeerEthernet24'  'Ethernet23' 'Ethernet22']` isn't a valid python literal.

Comment: @tdelaney indeed thats why i asked haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have an iterable that you want to convert to a space-separated string. The `str.join` method does that:

```
>>> test = ['PeerEthernet23', 'PeerEthernet24', 'Ethernet23', 'Ethernet22']
>>> " ".join(test)
'PeerEthernet23 PeerEthernet24 Ethernet23 Ethernet22'
```

your script would be

```
host_dict['actives'] = " ".join(get_po_bound_ints['result'][1]
    ['portChannels'][mac_to_eth2]['activePorts'].keys())
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Replacing commas with empty strings (assuming your list is named `my_list`):

```
print(str(my_list).replace(',', ''))
```